# How to increase decompilation timeout in ghidra?

Tags: ghidra

I'm trying to decompile a function with ghidra 9.0. After a (short) while, I get :

```
Exception while decompiling 140062b00: process: timeout
```

I already "succesfully" decompiled this function using IDA hexrays and snowman. Both return a massive function with several thousand lines of code. I use quotes because I didn't validate the whole output, but the parts that I analysed made sense.

I'm thinking that this timeout error could be solved by increasing the time limit, but I haven't found any way of configuring this.

Is there any way to use ghidra to decompile this function anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the timeout in decompiler options. Go to Edit->Tool Options...->Decompiler and change "Decompiler Timeout (seconds)" to the desired value.